# How to initialize a 2D C-style array from a nested std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, multidimensional-array, stdinitializerlist

I am creating a `Matrix<type, width, height>` class which I want to be able to initialize using `initializer_list`, for instance:

```
Matrix<int, 2, 2> mat = Matrix<int, 2, 2>{ {1,2},{3,4} };
```

The matrix is implemented using a `T[height][width]` 2D array.

To do this, I have tried making a constructor such as:

```
Matrix(std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list<T>> input);
```

However, I do not know how to fill the array with from the list. I have tried

- using `memcpy` (corrupted memory),
- `std::copy` (seems it is not possible to copy from an
  `std::initializer_list`),
- as well as used the *assignment operator* and `()` constructor call
  (but 2D arrays are not assignable and () constructor call does not
  compile).

Is there any other way, preferably as safe as possible, to do this?

Comment: Hint: range-`for` is your friend.

Comment: Since an initializer_list is implemented by an underlying array (according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)) I suppose you could memcpy from the pointer to the first element returned by `begin()` (the begin() of each row element; the outer list contains only the proxy initializer_lists). It would be totally anti-paradigmatic but what the heck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should provide exact type to the `Matrix(std::initializer_list</* here */> list);`.
Then to fill the array, you need to iterate through the list passed and fill the array. **([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4FjE9yNKSC29YKpj))**

```
#include <initializer_list> // std::initializer_list

template<typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class Matrix
{
    T mArray2D[R][C]{};

public:
    Matrix(const std::initializer_list<T[C]> list)
    //                                 ^^^^^ --> type of the row
    {
        auto iter{ list.begin() }; // returns pointer to T[C]
        for (std::size_t row{}; row < R; ++row)
        {
            const auto& rowElements{ *iter };
            for (std::size_t col{}; col < C; ++col)
            {
                mArray2D[row][col] = rowElements[col];
            }
            ++iter;
        }
    }
};
```

Now in the `main()` you can initialize `Matrix` using an initializer list as follows:

```
Matrix<int, 2, 2> mat{ {1,2}, {3,4} };
// or
// Matrix<int, 2, 2> mat = { {1,2}, {3,4} };
```

---

If you could use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), you could do the following. **([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pIZyANPTwim0BzXN))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>            // std::array
#include <initializer_list> // std::initializer_list

template<typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class Matrix
{
    using RowType = std::array<T, C>;
    T mArray2D[R][C]{};

public:
    Matrix(const std::initializer_list<RowType> list)
    {
        auto iter{ list.begin() };
        for (std::size_t row{}; row < R; ++row)
        {
            const RowType& rowElements{ *iter };
            for (std::size_t col{}; col < C; ++col)
            {
                mArray2D[row][col] = rowElements[col];
            }
            ++iter;
        }
    }
};
```

---

If the multidimensional array in the class could be an *`std::array` of `std::array` of type `T`*, you could use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) as well. **([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1jf0MaeZkDEym35X))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>            // std::array
#include <initializer_list> // std::initializer_list
#include <algorithm>        // std::copy

template<typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class Matrix
{
    using RowType = std::array<T, C>;
    using Array2D = std::array<RowType, R>;
    Array2D mArray{ RowType{} }; // initialize the matrix

public:
    Matrix(const std::initializer_list<RowType> list)
    {
       std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), mArray.begin());
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, changed the underlying array to std::array and used your suggestion, and it works great!

Comment: @kubci98 There was a typo in the previous solution and now I have added the solution for plain c style arrays. Check out the updates.